# add liquidity to a curve pool

Tags: solidity, foundry, curve

I am working on adding liquidity to a curve pool in Foundry in order to test the curve pool oracle in my project, however, I'm getting some difficulty in adding liquidity to a curve pool. I believe the pool is set up correctly and all the prerequisite conditions are met, but in foundry, I kept getting "EvmError: Revert" message. Wondering why this is the case.

```
   ├─ [104547] 0xedCe214e7a52c77914342B072230ac971149Eb00::add_liquidity([2000000000000000000000000, 2000000000000000000000000], 0) 
    │   ├─ [81494] 0x73Ec37618683C274D0bBf5f5726aA856B2BDAB81::add_liquidity([2000000000000000000000000, 2000000000000000000000000], 0) [delegatecall]
    │   │   ├─ [23005] 0x730D5ab5a375c3a6cDC22A9D3bEc1573FDeA97D6::transferFrom(0x9aF2E2B7e57c1CD7C68C5C3796d8ea67e0018dB7, 0xedCe214e7a52c77914342B072230ac971149Eb00, 2000000000000000000000000) 
    │   │   │   ├─ emit Approval(owner: 0x9aF2E2B7e57c1CD7C68C5C3796d8ea67e0018dB7, spender: 0xedCe214e7a52c77914342B072230ac971149Eb00, value: 0)
    │   │   │   ├─ emit Transfer(from: 0x9aF2E2B7e57c1CD7C68C5C3796d8ea67e0018dB7, to: 0xedCe214e7a52c77914342B072230ac971149Eb00, value: 2000000000000000000000000)
    │   │   │   └─ ← 0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001
    │   │   ├─ [22217] 0xaf88d065e77c8cC2239327C5EDb3A432268e5831::transferFrom(0x9aF2E2B7e57c1CD7C68C5C3796d8ea67e0018dB7, 0xedCe214e7a52c77914342B072230ac971149Eb00, 2000000000000000000000000) 
    │   │   │   ├─ [21678] 0x0f4fb9474303d10905AB86aA8d5A65FE44b6E04A::transferFrom(0x9aF2E2B7e57c1CD7C68C5C3796d8ea67e0018dB7, 0xedCe214e7a52c77914342B072230ac971149Eb00, 2000000000000000000000000) [delegatecall]
    │   │   │   │   ├─ emit Transfer(from: 0x9aF2E2B7e57c1CD7C68C5C3796d8ea67e0018dB7, to: 0xedCe214e7a52c77914342B072230ac971149Eb00, value: 2000000000000000000000000)
    │   │   │   │   └─ ← 0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001
    │   │   │   └─ ← 0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001
    │   │   └─ ← "EvmError: Revert"
    │   └─ ← "EvmError: Revert"
    └─ ← "EvmError: Revert"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the [code](https://arbiscan.io/token/0xedce214e7a52c77914342b072230ac971149eb00#code) the call fails here:

```
# Invariant after change
D1: uint256 = self.get_D_mem(rates, new_balances, amp)
assert D1 > D0 // this assert fails!
```

Are you planning to provide liquidity with a ratio of 1-1?

Note that USDC has 6 decimals of precision and the other token has 18. Depending on how you set the original price, this could cause the problem.

Comment: You nailed it. It's exactly the issue of USDC decimals. Many thanks.